# Custom Google Search using ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-custom-search

I am trying to do a custom Google search using ajax call.

I searched in Google and found a [good link](http://www.searchtools.com/analysis/google-cse-ajax-basic-example.html).

Here a textbox and a button is coming automatically and when we click the search button the result is showing in the div.

But I want to search the item which is written in my self created textbox.
Means:Manually I created a textbox and a button. I want to show result when i click my button with the query written in my textbox.

Please help

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

write this in submit button

```
// get a custom search control & keep it in cseControl
// note: put your own custom search ID number here
var cseControl = new google.search.CustomSearchControl('009827885688477640989:igzwimalyta');
// open pages from search results clicks on the same page
cseControl.setLinkTarget(google.search.Search.LINK_TARGET_SELF);
 // when there are no matches, explain why
cseControl.setNoResultsString("Sorry, there are no pages in this web site that match all the search terms.");
// make the search field visible in div with ID 'cseDiv'
 cseControl.draw('divGoogleResult');

 cseControl.execute(userInput);
 $('.gsc-search-box').hide();
```